# Strange sqlite3 behavior

Tags: sqlite

I'm working on a small SQLite database using the Unix command line sqlite3 command tool. My schema is:

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE status (id text, date integer, status text, mode text);
```

Now I want to set the column 'mode' to the string "Status" for all entries. However, if I type this:

```
sqlite> UPDATE status SET mode="Status";
```

Instead of setting column 'mode' to the string "Status", it sets every entry to the value that is currently in the column 'status'. Instead, if I type the following it does the expected behavior:

```
sqlite> UPDATE status SET mode='Status';
```

Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 1):

This is also a FAQ :-

**My WHERE clause expression column1="column1" does not work. It causes every row of the table to be returned, not just the rows where column1 has the value "column1".**

Use single-quotes, not double-quotes, around string literals in SQL. This is what the SQL standard requires. Your WHERE clause expression should read: column1='column2'

SQL uses double-quotes around identifiers (column or table names) that contains special characters or which are keywords. So double-quotes are a way of escaping identifier names. Hence, when you say column1="column1" that is equivalent to column1=column1 which is obviously always true.

http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q24

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's normal in SQL.

Single quotes are used for string values; double quotes are used for identifiers (like table or column names).
(See the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).)